# What is a word or phrase that describes an object whose importance depends on its recentness?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, a newspaper. In general, last week's newspaper is much less relevant than today's. I want to use it in a sentence like: "Since newspapers are ____ in nature, it's important to be notified the moment a new issue comes out." Temporal is the only thing I can think of, but not really since I don't want to emphasize the object's impermanence.

Comment: _ephemeral_ is the word.

Comment: @Xann 'Ephemeral' is *a* word, but not a good fit here. I suppose you could say their *value* is ephemeral.. still doesn't seem quite right to me though.

Comment: Go to your local library and ask for the section *Ephemera* -- you'll find the newspapers there.  Vital today, lining the bottom of your budgie's cage tomorrow.

Answer (score 5):

When English speakers can't think of a single word for something, they sometimes stick words together to make a phrase.  That's the case with ***time-sensitive***, which the Cambridge Dictionary helpfully defines:

> **time-sensitive**
>   adjective UK ​ US ​
>   ​
>   used to describe a product that has to be delivered by a particular time, or information that is only useful for a particular period:
>   We deliver high-value, time-sensitive goods like cars, computers and specialist chemicals.
>   time-sensitive documents

The word *ephemeral* suggested by a commenter conveys the brevity of something's life span, but it fails to deliver an indication of value.

We can raise the stakes on ***time-sensitive*** (a newspaper, in the original post) to ***time-critical*** (in the case of a shipment of vaccine for an outbreak of gomps in a remote corner of Rumtifoo).

Answer (score 1):

I see you did mention temporal, the first thing that came my mind was **temporal relevance** (of the news, I don't think that emphasises the *object*'s impermanence).

You could also borrow the phrase [**time value**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_value_of_money) from finance (i.e. the 'time value of money' - £1 in your hand today is worth more than the promise of £1 later).

You could riff on that idea without the jargon by talking about newspapers' **waning**/**depreciating** **relevance**.

Another phrase might be '**of the moment**' or similar.